# What does "tenure over" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have a table showing who (among a group of people) attended a series of meetings occuring on different days. It goes like this:

> Person's name: date 1: date 2, etc.
>
> Jack: ✓: x, etc.

Some people have the phrase "tenure over" hanging in front of their names under certain dates instead of a check or X mark. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

**Tenure** can refer to the length of time a person holds a particular position, for example, on a committee, or in elected office.  When the tenure is *over*, they are no longer in that position. They have held the position for the designated length of time.

> During his tenure as mayor, Mr Jones was a good friend to commercial
>   developers, not an ally of local neighborhoods. Now that his tenure is over, local groups are hoping to prevent construction of two casinos he had fast-tracked.
>
> Next year, her tenure on the school board will be over, and she plans to run for the state senate.